# Zookeeper/Kafka with Tomcat - Possible At All?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, tomcat8

I was wondering if someone has used zookeeper/kafka embeeded within Tomcat. I know that Kafka requires Zookeeper, but does it mean that I have to run Kafka and Zookeeper as separate instances? So far I cannot see any use cases where everything has been bolt in. Could anyone advise?

My question is more around the concept of using zookeeper and kafka as a jar within the same tomcat web application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Kafka and Zookeeper are meant to be used in a stand-alone fashion, run as separate processes.

They should even be on different machines/vms/containers than the tomcat web application.

You also probably want a Zookeeper cluster of 3-5 machines, rather than a single one, at least for production.

Both of them have Java clients though, for you to interact from the web application with them, and those are OK to include.

Comment: that's actually what I really wanted to hear :). I hate wrapping/chaining things into Tomcat. I hope you have a good day sir!